# Is there a variant of git checkout -m that doesn't switch your branch

Tags: git

In git, is there a command that works like `git checkout -m <commit>` but does not detach HEAD?

I have a dirty working directory and want to rebase it on top of an incoming commit. `git checkout -m <commit>` does most of it, but because I want to re-attach `HEAD` I need to do a `echo 'ref: refs/head/<old-branch>' > .git/HEAD`. Can you do it without this?

Old:
e.g, Can I start a merge between the working directory and `<commit>` and remain on the current branch.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Are you trying to cherry-pick a commit (merge it) with the existing working directory ?

Comment: Usually you would just commit your working copy and then say `git merge <commit>`

Comment: Why don't you want to avoid detaching HEAD?  Once it's detached you can still do everything you can normally do.  The only difference is that unless you create a branch or a tag you'll lose the changes you've made.  That's why you run `git branch foo` before going back to master.

Comment: Mayur Nagekar : sure, but without creating a commit

Answer (score 1):

Yeah just cd into your top level dir and add "." at the end of your checkout command.  Eg let's say you are on master and you want to pull in the changes from dev but without creating a new commit and without switching to dev.  Then you could type:

```
git checkout dev .
```

The . is just saying what files to take from the dev branch, in your case you want the everything so you just specify the current dir with . (which is why you want to be in the top level repo dir when you do this)

You'll see you're now still on master but you have the changes from dev as uncommitted modified files.

Beware this doesn't attempt any kind of merging or rebasing, it just pulls in the files from the other branch.

If you want to merge stuff into a dirty branch, I'd strongly suggest committing your dirt into a temporary branch and then doing a regular merge.  This way you don't risk losing any work, and you can always discard the temporary branch if you don't like what you see.

Comment: Just to be sure: `git checkout dev -- .`

Comment: This won't work - it will erase the old files rather than merging against them.

Comment: @user3623227 It isn't clear to me that he wants a merge -- seems like he wants something more like a checkout since his question used checkout as the starting point.  But actually re-reading the question I see the word "rebase" which you're right this solution certainly will not do, it will overwrite as you've pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
git merge <msg> HEAD <commit_sha>
```

Eg

```
git merge test HEAD 9eef2c89753895da807c936ff1ba3a255c8370c9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stash your working copy changes, checkout all the files in `<commit>` (but not update `HEAD`) and then pop the stash:

```
git stash
git checkout `<commit>` .    # in working copy root directory
git stash pop
```

This will preserve your working copy and index modifications by applying them over the contents of `<commit>`.

In case of conflicts, you'll have to manually discard the stash (`git stash drop`) after resolving them.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a variant of git checkout -m that doesn't switch your branch?

You can find examples with Git 2.43 (Q4 2023): "[`checkout --merge  -- path`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5bb67fb7ab035ef399d019440f184aee3608f3e7/Documentation/git-checkout.txt#L249)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt---merge))</sup> and `update-index --unresolve` path did not resurrect conflicted state that was resolved to remove path, but now they do.

See [commit 5bdedac](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5bdedac3c7b0894643256304cd5f0dd29cf8eec9), [commit ed3789f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ed3789f2f0ab8b8d5e325e47f0caf02b6bd9edfc), [commit 54f98fe](https://github.com/git/git/commit/54f98fee5069f50c6e96687504b82a7695c8648a), [commit c0a4ae7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c0a4ae7f4e010204f8341dcc3b9217dd42baee14), [commit 35901f1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/35901f1c2461640019e70bbefecdce1f59f660d2), [commit fe83269](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fe83269e16c1fd57df42c2a22a2b9ee621175a75), [commit 91e0705](https://github.com/git/git/commit/91e07058c5663d01d39a00418c91415d0227d53c) (31 Jul 2023) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5bb67fb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5bb67fb7ab035ef399d019440f184aee3608f3e7), 02 Oct 2023)</sup>

> ### [`checkout/restore`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/54f98fee5069f50c6e96687504b82a7695c8648a): refuse unmerging paths unless checking out of the index

> Recreating unmerged index entries using resolve-undo data, recreating conflicted working tree files using unmerged index entries, and writing data out of unmerged index entries, make sense only when we are checking paths out of the index and not when we are checking paths out of a tree-ish.
>
> Add an extra check to make sure "`--merge`" and "`--ours`/`--theirs`" options are rejected when checking out from a tree-ish, update the document (especially the SYNOPSIS section) to highlight that they are incompatible, and add a few tests to make sure the combination fails.

`git checkout` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/54f98fee5069f50c6e96687504b82a7695c8648a/Documentation/git-checkout.txt#L15-L18):

> ```
> git checkout [-f] <tree-ish> [--] <pathspec>...
> git checkout [-f] <tree-ish> --pathspec-from-file=<file> [--pathspec-file-nul]
> git checkout [-f|--ours|--theirs|-m|--conflict=<style>] [--] <pathspec>...
> git checkout [-f|--ours|--theirs|-m|--conflict=<style>] --pathspec-from-file=<file> [--pathspec-file-nul]
> ```
>
> This option cannot be
> used when checking out paths from a tree-ish.

`git restore` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/54f98fee5069f50c6e96687504b82a7695c8648a/Documentation/git-restore.txt#L81-L82):

> This option cannot be used when checking out paths from a
> tree-ish (i.e. with the `--source` option).